# Logstash: Parsing apache access log's timestamp leads to parse failure

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to parse common apache access log files which is this:

```
::1 - - [02/Mar/2014:15:36:43 +0100] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3133
```

This is my filter section:

```
grok {
      match => ["message", "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}"]
}
date {
    match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
}
```

All fields are getting recognized, but not the timestamp. The output on the console is the following:

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"timestamp", :value=>"02/Mar/2014:15:36:43 +0100", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "02/Mar/2014:15:36:43 +0100" is malformed at "Mar/2014:15:36:43 +0100", :level=>:warn}
```

I already checked the docs for date filter. It relies on [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

What have I done wrong? Can't see the mistake.

Comment: Works for me; I get 2014-03-02T14:36:43.000Z as the timestamp for this exact input and configuration. Is your default locale a non-English one so you need to [set the locale for the date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date#locale)?

Comment: Thanks, works fine. If you want you can write this as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `is malformed at "Mar/2014:15:36:43 +0100"` part of the error message indicates that the timestamp parser has a problem with the month name. This suggests that the default locale is something other than English (specifically, a language where the third month isn't abbreviated "Mar"). This can be solved by explicitly setting the locale used for the [date filter's](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) parsing:

```
filter {
  date {
    ...
    locale => "en"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is apache access log always uses `en` as locale setting?